# Type mismatch in scala while using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

```
package week1
import math.abs
object newton {
    def abs(x:Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x

    def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
        if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
        else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)

    def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double)=
        abs(guess*guess - x  < 0.001)

    def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =
        (guess + x/guess)/2

    def sqrt (x:Double)= sqrtIter(1.0,x)

}
```

at line

```
abs (guess*guess - x <0.001)
```

eclipse shows the following error

> type mismatch;  found   : Boolean  required: Double    newton.sc   /progfun/src/week1  line 10 Scala Problem

How do I solve this? It's my first time running scala and I'm using the exact code from Functional Programmming class currently going on in Coursera.

Comment: Also not sure why you import math.abs only to define your own abs function later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
abs (guess*guess - x <0.001)
```

returns a boolean, since it first evaluates guess*guess - x, and than compares it to 0.001.

You should do this

```
abs (guess*guess - x) < 0.001
```